# Update to sitecore 8.2 giving error for Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Sitecore.DependencyInjection.ComponentServicesConfigurator

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8.1, sitecore8.2

I have upgraded from Sitecore 8.1 to Sitecore 8.2. I am getting following error:

```
Could not find type: Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Sitecore.DependencyInjection.ComponentServicesConfigurator, Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Sitecore [<configurator type="Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Sitecore.DependencyInjection.ComponentServicesConfigurator, Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Sitecore" />]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Hi Namita,

Did you ever find a resolution to this? I am having the same problem.

Thanks,

Jason.

Comment: @ Jason I had following line in my code. GlobalConfiguration.Configure(config => config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()). I just removed this.

Answer (score 1):

The assembly : Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Sitecore might be from old Sitecore Version. Please reference the one  from latest SC version.

New namespace added : Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Sitecore.DependencyInjection

Please verify the fix.